# Wordpress: dummy data from theme Appointment doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, appointment, dummy-data

I have downloaded the dummy data for the theme appointment. While uploading the xml file it was displayed that most of the elements of the dummy data could not be added. can anyone help me?
it is this xml dummy data https://webriti.com/themes/dummydata/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with the demo data plugin for loading the dummy content.